# Visual patterns in memory?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, memory

Started up remote debugging a C++ project today on a Win 7 machine running in VMWare and was astonished to see the following pattern on a random memory location:

[image]

Who might code this (it's not me!) and for what reason?? Just curious if anyone has seen something like this.

Comment: Yep, agreed.  Those look like grey-level colour masks for four zeros.  It may just be left-overs from an old bitmap buffer.  Don't worry about it unless you start seeing `QQ` and `=P` appear everywhere.  Then, you should suspect that HAL9000 is messing with your app.

Comment: At least it's not some logo for a hacker group bundled with a rootkit.

Comment: This is an awesome example of how frequency analysis can defeat obfuscation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks like a rendered mask for a font (each character in a font (typeface+size+style) is rendered once in-memory, then blitted to the output surface) using 8bpp, which suggests you've got font anti-aliasing enabled.

I'm assuming your project involves a GUI, you might be looking at a shared-memory area that GDI uses for storing rasterized fonts.

If not, then this might just be leftover memory from a previous process or OS component that wasn't zeroed before being used by your application.

Comment: Perhaps they zeroed it a little too well.

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to say. Possibly memory used to buffer some fonts (in this case, zeros), or even buffered printer or screen content.

Comment: It's unlikely to be from a screen or window buffer because it's 8bpp.

Comment: Well, assuming a modern display, you're right. I've updated my answer to include printers.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Of course, how could I miss it. I thought I'm going crazy when I first saw it :) Too much debugging :)

Comment: No, you're all wrong. We're living in the Matrix and you've found a way to tap into the Matrix code. What you're seeing is the very nature of our constructed reality, right before your eyes - except you need to change your IDE's settings to use green-on-black.