# Is there a way to use a python script for debugging C++ app's memory in visual studio?

Tags: python, c++, debugging, visual-studio-2019

When debugging my c++ code, I would like, when a I hit a breakpoint, to open an interactive python window (similar to "Evaluate Expression" in pycharm) and run a visualization/inspection script on variables in memory. I s there an extension for VS2019 that enables it?

Comment: AFAIK, the Watch can evaluate simple expressions to a certain amount. (If I remember right `gdb` can it even better but I haven't used it anymore for a long time.) Please, note that C++ is a compiled language (at least in VS2019) where Python is an interpreted language. (I already heard that Python can be compiled as well as C++ can be interpreted but I doubt that's relevant here.)

Comment: Hi Hadar, what's the special reason you need to run a python script when debugging C++ code? How about using the [Memory windows in the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/memory-windows?view=vs-2019)? Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468194/how-to-read-the-debug-memory-window-in-visual-studio). Hope I didn't misunderstand anything :)

Comment: Hi @LanceLi-MSFT, for example, I develop image processing tools, and I would like to actually see the image in different stages of the processing while debugging and stopping at a breakpoint. I imagined something like a debugger window that can take a pointer and a size, create a numpy array from it and display it using matplotlib or something similar.

Comment: @Scheff thank you, please see my above comment, I'm already familiar with what you wrote

Comment: I've never done it by myself - just heard it's possible: [MSDN: Starting to Develop Visual Studio Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2019). We wrote some debugger visualizers for VS2013, for a convenient output of our own "fundamental" types. However, visualizer means textual visualizer in Auto / Locals / Watch view. Not sure, if it can display images as well (but I doubt).