# Convert char array to byte array

Tags: c++, c

I have a string declared like so.

```
CHAR bkp[40] = "dc74699a8381da395f10b"; <- this value comes from querying a registry value
```

In memory (using VS memory window) I see..

```
0x00000071432FF918 64 63 37 34 36 39 39 61 38 33 38 31 64 61 33 39 35 66 31 30 62 00 .. .. .. ..
```

I am trying to convert the string to memory so that when I examine that memory address I see..

```
0x00000071432FF918 dc 74 69 9a 83 81 da 39 5f 10 0b .. .. .. ..
```

My project is in C++ but the function requires that it gets returned to a `char *`. So if the char array needs to be converted to a C++ string it can.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking since the terms "char array" and "byte array" are interchangable in C

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. Then define "byte array" specifically, i.e. whether you mean you want to view the string instead of the ASCII bytes making it up, or want some container of `std::byte`, or what.

Comment: Looks like they want an alphanumeric sequence to be treated as a hexadecimal sequence.

Comment: `printf("%02x", bkp[0]);` will print `64`; `printf("%c", bkp[0])` will print `d`.

Comment: VS has a "Hexadecimal Display" option when viewing a variable. It's the same data. Just the way it is displayed gets changed. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: If the string contains a `"00"` pair (decoding to byte value 0), that would appear as a null terminator if the returned `char *` is to be treated as a null terminated string. So you should probably return the length as well. Also, `unsigned char *` would be preferable to `char *` for dealing with bytes.

Comment: I don't get why these answers are conversion code, I thought OP wanted to see Ascii representation of memory in VS debugger? The VS memory debug window gives you just that. While paused during debugging (breakpoint, crash, etc), in VS2013 at least (ancient I know, not my choice), go to DEBUG menu -> Windows -> Memory -> <up to 4 memory windows available>. In the memory window, you can type in your address (or variable expresssion corresponding to an address), and you will see the hex in the left columns and ascii in the right columns.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with the Memory window, this might help you get started on how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468194/how-to-read-the-debug-memory-window-in-visual-studio

Comment: Note: The string `dc74699a8381da395f10b` is `21` characters long. This is likely a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert you character array to a binary. Your input array is a hex string so this is rather straigforward.

```
unsigned char toBinary(char c)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        return c - '0';

    return (c - 'a') + 10;
}

CHAR bkp[40] = "dc74699a8381da395f10b"
unsigned char b[20];

int bi = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 40; i += 2)
{
    char c = bkp[i];
    unsigned char v = toBinary(bkp[i]) << 4;
    v += toBinary(bkp[i+1])

    b[bi++] = v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply iterate through the string, and for every 2-char pair, you can do some very simple calculations and bit shifts to extract the byte values.  For example:

```cpp
BYTE decodeHex(char c)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        return c - '0';
    else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
        return (c - 'A') + 10;
    else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
        return (c - 'a') + 10;
    else
        // illegal! throw something...
}

CHAR bkp[] = "dc74699a8381da395f100b";
int slen = strlen(bkp);

BYTE *bytes = new BYTE[slen / 2];
int blen = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < slen; i += 2)
{
    bytes[blen++] = (decodeHex(bkp[i]) << 4) | decodeHex(bkp[i+1]);
}

// use bytes up to blen as needed...

delete[] bytes;
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for the update, I forgot about the `+10`.

Answer (score 1):

The *array* is a character string, so you'll have to convert from characters to hex.
Let's use the old fashioned method:

```
const unsigned int length = sizeof(bkp);
const std::string hex_digits = "0123456789abcdef";
std::vector<uint8_t> destination;
for (unsigned int index = 0U; index < length; index += 2U)
{
    uint8_t byte_value = 0;
    std::string::size_type  position = hex_digits.find(bkp[index]);
    if (position == std::string::npos)
    {
       std::cerr << "invalid hex value at position " << index << "\n";
       break;
    }
    byte_value = position;
    ++index;
    position = hex_digits.find(bkp[index]);
    if (position == std::string::npos)
    {
       std::cerr << "invalid hex value at position " << index << "\n";
       break;
    }
    byte_value = (byte_value * 256) + position;
    destination.push_back(byte_value);
}
```

*Note:  the above code uses C++ features since the original post was tagged as C++.*

Answer (score 0):

Just for some fun, you can perform the conversion using non-conditional operations.

In general:

- 'A' = 64, 'a' = 96, both of which have bit 6 set (value 64 decimal)
- '0' = 48, so does not have the 6th bit set.

You can take the input, take the lower 4 bits to give us the 0->9, A->F or a->f and then take bit 6 and use it as a multiplier to add the +10 if needed.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void HexStrToRaw(char* in, unsigned char* out)
{
    for (int loop = 0, o_loop = 0; loop < strlen(in); loop += 2, o_loop++)
    {
        out[o_loop] = (((in[loop] & 15) + ((in[loop] >> 6) * 9)) << 4) | ((in[loop + 1] & 15) + ((in[loop + 1] >> 6) * 9));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char          in[40] = "dc74699a8381da395f10b";
    unsigned char out[20];

    HexStrToRaw(in, out);
    for (int loop = 0; loop < sizeof(out); loop++)
    {
        printf("%d -> 0x%02x\n", loop, out[loop]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output becomes:

```
0 -> 0xdc
1 -> 0x74
2 -> 0x69
3 -> 0x9a
4 -> 0x83
5 -> 0x81
6 -> 0xda
7 -> 0x39
8 -> 0x5f
9 -> 0x10
10 -> 0xb0
11 -> 0xcc
12 -> 0xcc
13 -> 0xcc
14 -> 0xcc
15 -> 0xcc
16 -> 0xcc
17 -> 0xcc
18 -> 0xcc
19 -> 0xcc
```